# Oracle rownum returning wrong result

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying a query to return only the latest row from table.

Initially I used max(id) in query
But as I use sequence and my envoirnment is clustered, I cannot rely on sequence as its out of order.
So I decided to order based on creation time and pick top row using rownum.

I used something like

```
SELECT  A.id
    FROM Table_A, Table_B B
    WHERE A.status = 'COMPLETED'
    AND B.name = 'some_name'
    AND A.id = B.id
    AND rownum = 1
    order by A.Creation_Time;
```

This some how returns me some wrong result say 42145.
If I remove the rownum condtn the top record is differnet say 45343;

Comment: If in doubt, read the manual. That's all explained there: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using `rownum` with `order by`, you need to use a subquery.  This has to do with the order of evaluation of the `where` and `order by`.  So, try this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT A.id
      FROM Table_A JOIN 
           Table_B B
           ON A.id = B.id
      WHERE A.status = 'COMPLETED' AND B.name = 'some_name'
      ORDER BY A.Creation_Time
     ) ab
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

I should add:  Oracle 12 supports `fetch first 1 row only`, which is more convenient:

```
  SELECT A.id
  FROM Table_A JOIN 
       Table_B B
       ON A.id = B.id
  WHERE A.status = 'COMPLETED' AND B.name = 'some_name'
  ORDER BY A.Creation_Time
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked as expected, just had to had order in descending order.

Answer (score -1):

Any chance you meant to do this? (Specifying to order DESC)

```
SELECT  A.id
    FROM Table_A, Table_B B
    WHERE A.status = 'COMPLETED'
    AND B.name = 'some_name'
    AND A.id = B.id
    AND rownum = 1
    order by A.Creation_Time DESC;
```

EDIT: Obviously specifying order DESC was critical to your query. I had to upvote Gordon also, since he's completely correct that you need to limit the rows returned after sorting, so the methods he suggests are perfect for that. So, for anyone reading this far, I wanted to leave no doubt that rownum is assigned after the where clause is processed but before sorting or aggregation ([source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html)).

NB: As good as Gordon's answer is, there is one more consideration that may or may not be important here. It seems that it might be possible to have duplicate values of A.Creation_Time, which could cause you to see non-deterministic behavior as far as which of the duplicate rows might be returned when executing that query. If that problem might arise, Tom Kyte (same link as earlier) suggests adding some unique column value to the order by clause as an easy dodge. For example:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT A.id, A.Creation_Time
            FROM Table_A A 
            JOIN Table_B B
            ON A.id = B.id
            WHERE A.status = 'COMPLETED' AND B.name = 'some_name'
           )
      ORDER BY Creation_Time, rowid DESC 
     ) t
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Where ROWID is a unique pseudo column that can serve the purpose.